# Playing for bragging rights

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, expressions

What does playing for bragging rights mean in English and is it common and understood in everyday speech by all people?
I have found some dictionary definitions, but I couldn't understand its precise meaning. I wonder if you could help me to realize what does it exactly mean?

**Example:**

> - Do you play for money, bragging rights, or other? [[Source]](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/fantasyfootball/comments/992fyk/do_you_play_for_money_bragging_rights_or_other/)

Comment: [Bragging rights](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bragging%20rights): ": entitlement to boast about something." What is unclear about that definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the term 'bragging rights' is pretty common and most native English speakers would know what you mean.

Playing for bragging rights means that the only thing the winner will get out of winning, is to say to everyone that they won. They are playing for the right to talk highly about their winning.